# Download historical prices for multiple stocks

Tags: yahoo-api

Here's what I tried (from one suggestion in this group):

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader

symbols = ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MMM', 'ACN', 'A', 'ADP']

pnls = {i:dreader.DataReader(i,'yahoo','1985-01-01','2016-09-01') for i in symbols}
```

this is the error
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=473380200&period2=1472768999&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history

Here's another code that does not seem to work:

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['TSLA', 'TWTR', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AAPL']
interval = '1d'
period1 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 23, 59).timetuple()))
period2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 31, 23, 59).timetuple()))

xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('historicalprices.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

for ticker in tickers:
    query_string = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
    df = pd.read_csv(query_string)
    df.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name=ticker, index = False)

xlwriter.save()
```

this is the error:

HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

This code works for individual stocks:

```
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('AAPL')
data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date='2021-12-01', end_date='2022-05-31', 
                                                  time_interval='daily')
aapl_df = pd.DataFrame(data['AAPL']['prices'])
aapl_df = aapl_df.drop('date', axis=1).set_index('formatted_date')

aapl_df.to_csv('/Users/rangapriyas/Desktop/Prices/AAPL.csv')
```

I am new to python can anyone help me with a for loop on this above code pls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for anyone who may benefit:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'WMT', 'IBM', 'MU', 'BA', 'AXP']

# Fetch the data
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers_list,'2015-1-1', '2022-05-31')['Adj Close']

# Print first 5 rows of the data
print(data.head())
```